# VIM and SPF13 Configuration

Tags: vim, spf13vim

I'm new to VIM and have been forcing myself to use it since every hardcore dev I know swears by it. I've been just doing my own thing and using vanilla vim with some syntax highlighting and things like that. It was recommended that I try SPF13 and so far it seems pretty awesome.

Although, one thing really kills me and that's when I'm in insert mode. It seems that any time I'm in insert and I move my cursor, it takes me out of insert and it's a huge pain in the ass when doing anything more than just fixing a quick thing. Does anyone know how to disable this or have tips on how to manage without wanting to throw my notebook?

It's really slowing down my development.

Comment: I would recommend not using SPF13. Distributions (such as SPF13) have complex structures that are not normal to vim. They also include a lot of features/mapping you will never know are there because you didn't put them there. I would recommend starting with a clean slate. Add mappings and plugins as you see a need for them (and read the documentation of the plugins you install). If you do it this way you will know where the problem occurred and be able to fix it since you know what changed.

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks! I thought that using something like that might make things a bit easier for me but it seems like that may not be the case.

Comment: I've been using Vim for years and I completely agree with @FDinoff. Learn Vim without plugins and keep your .vimrc file clean to begin with.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use arrow keys to move your cursor around while in insert mode. This is not the vim way. You should try to get into the habit of leaving insert mode when you want to do movement.

Comment: While I agree with the above comments about SPF13, your problem has nothing to do with it.  You should be able to move the cursor with the arrows both in insert and it normal mode.  If you don't, either your `TERM` is set to the wrong value, or the `termcap` / `terminfo` entry for your terminal is not in synch with what your terminal actually sends.  This is generally a pain in the rear to debug, but it definitely can be done.

Comment: Please report what `:set term?` returns, what OS is on your laptop, and whether or not the error persists if you start vim with `vim -U NONE`. As @lcd047 says, something's wrong with your terminal setup. (Micah is also correct in that you shouldn't get into a habit of using arrow keys in the insert mode; but that doesn't mean what you are experiencing is not an error.)

Comment: @lcd047 While you are probably correct, I still don't think this belongs in their vimrc https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/blob/3.0/.vimrc#L64. I feel that this "fix" is hiding some bigger problem.

Comment: @FDinoff Heh, yeah, that's evil, even for a canned solution like SPF13.

Comment: Ended up just removing SPF13 and writing my own .vimrc. Definitely better and I'm just adding things as I need them. Thanks for all the advice!